# Remove all .html in url string with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to remove all the ".html" (of url) for **each path of my website**. With the querys etc... So if I've file https://exemple.com/login.html, I want to only access it by https://exemple.com/login.

I have seen several similar answers on stackoverflow. Except that after each test, they do not work.
But, it doesnt work.

This is my code actualy :

```sh
#remove html file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.html will become https://example.com/file
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

AND

```sh
#remove html file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.html will become https://example.com/file
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

The two above do not work.

JUST, the next code works. But it only creates a simple redirect and the page is not displayed correctly (without content, we only receive the list of items in the directory managed by nginx) :

```sh
#remove html file extension-e.g. https://example.com/file.html will become https://example.com/file
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.html$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

So how I can do that ?
Is there documentation to properly use .htaccess ?

Thanks you.

Comment: and it'ss Apache rewrite rules not NGINX !!

Comment: What is the URL you are actually linking to? ie. the URL being requested?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite, I want to convert (it's an exemple) : https://site.fr/login.html and access to https://site.fr/login. And another url : https://site.fr/options/test.html to https://site.fr/options/test.
Do you think it's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```